# Practical application of complex FFT

Tags: fft, discrete-signals

Is there any application where one may need to compute the FFT of a complex-valued signal? I am interested in cases where the FFT of the complex-valued signal is of primary interest and is not an intermediate step in a larger computation, so cases like using analytic signals in the computation of the [Pseudo-Wigner-Ville](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0165-1684(84)90048-3) distribution is not of interest to me.

Comment: In digital communications, the baseband representation of a quadrature signal is complex. FFT analysis of such a signal is often done to find its bandwidth, identify SNR, potential interferers, etc.

Comment: Also an **inverse** FFT, which is almost the same thing as a forward FFT, would accept a complex input more often than a real one, and produces a real output more often than a complex one.

Comment: Subset of what @MBaz mentions but a really obvious application is in [Orthogonal Frequency Division Multiplexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_frequency-division_multiplexing). The complex FFT is instrumental in modulation and demodulation of the carrier signal.

Comment: @A_A Thanks for the wiki link. I will check it out.

Answer (score 3):

An SDR app (for example one for an RTL-SDR device plugged into a Raspberry Pi's USB port) which displays the RF spectrum of an IQ baseband signal uses the FFT of a complex input.  This allows showing the RF spectrum both above and below the PLL frequency.

Answer (score 3):

The importance of dealing with complex signals (or quadrature signals) is demonstrated for wireless systems, see for instance [Complex Signal Processing is Not Complex](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TCSI.2004.834522), K. W. Martin, 2004, and with narrow band or bandpass signals that have, in general,  a [complex-valued lowpass equivalent](http://www.cs.tut.fi/kurssit/TLT-9707/presentations/Complex-Signals-and-Radios-short-2pp.pdf), which is easier to deal with (lower rate for instance).

It is used for instance with radar and some geophysical signals that have a natural complex extension, as well as in   digital communications in general, spectroscopy, Magnetic Resonance Imaging, etc.

Practically speaking, one can also [compute the FFT of two (distinct) real signals at once](http://www.staderini.eu/wordpress/?page_id=8)